# How to use SIGSTOP, SIGCONT and SIGKILL for child process in C

Tags: c, linux, signals, fork, sigkill

I am writing a C program that uses fork(), execvp() for child process. I want to stop, continue and kill a child process, how can I handle it ? I don't know much about signals.

Comment: `kill(pid, SIGSTOP)` will stop the process, `kill(pid, SIGCONT)` will continue it. What more do you need to know?

Answer (score 0):

Call the [signal](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/csignal/signal/) function within a process to setup a signal handler, a function that will be called when that process receives the specific signal you specify.

Here's an example signal handler function for the SIGUSR1 signal:

```
static void usr1_signal_handler(int signo)
{
    printf("Received SIGUSR1!\n");
    finish_up = true;
}
```

and an example of how to set it up:

```
if (signal(SIGUSR1, usr1_signal_handler) == SIG_ERR) {
    printf("An error occurred while setting a signal handler.\n");
}
```

You can signal a process using the [kill](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Signaling-Another-Process.html) function:

```
kill(pid, SIGUSR1);
```

In this case, pid could be the process id you receive when you call fork.

Comment: You can't safely call `printf()` in a signal handler.  https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#note188